# BootstrapVue Table Sticky Headers (CoreUI)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using [coreUI](https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/table.html) and I have a view where i set up a datatable. I want to have the thead sticky on top but nothing I do seems to work.

The thead consists of two rows (tr). one row contains the names of the headers and the second row contains some the column filters. These come right out the box with UI.

Whatever I tried only applies to the 2nd row and not the 1st.

eg. I have tried adding the below css code but only the second line seems to be working.

```
thead tr:nth-child(1) th { position: sticky; top: 0; }
thead tr:nth-child(2) th { position: sticky; top: 43px; }
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your css:

```
.b-table-sticky-header > .table.b-table > thead {
  position: sticky !important;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
thead tr:nth-child(1) th { position: sticky !important; top: 0; }
thead tr:nth-child(2) th { position: sticky !important; top: 43px; }
```